# java- bool func that gets an integer parameter and checks duplicates without array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, numbers

My task is to
write a function that gets an integer as input and
return true if the number has at lest 2 identical digits, false otherwise,
*without using special libraries or using arrays*

my code, but it only works for consecutive digits

```
    public static boolean check_num(int num) {
        int count = 1; //number itself
        int tmp = 0; 
        int tmp1 = 0;
        while (num != 0) {
            tmp = num % 10; 
            num /= 10; 
            tmp1 = num % 10; 
            while(count>=2) {
            if(tmp1==tmp) count++; 
            
        }
            }
        if(count==2 || count>2) return true;
        return false;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter number");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(check_num(num));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this task we need to track if an appropriate decimal digit has been found in the given number or not.  The simplest way could be to use a 10-element boolean array, but as long as the arrays are not allowed, another `int` number can be used to store the mapping of digits, for example, for a number `1234` the mapping would look like (lower bits last): `11110`.

The bit corresponding to a decimal digit is set using right shift and XOR operation `^`.  If the result of XOR is 0, then the duplicate digit is detected.

An example implementation may look like this (including debug messages):

```java
public static boolean checkNum(int n) {
    if (n < 10) return false; // no need to check 1-digit number
    
    int arr = 0;
    
    while (n > 0) {
        int digit = n % 10;
        int bit = 1 << digit;
        arr ^= bit;
        if (0 == (arr & bit)) {
            System.out.println("Dup found: " + Integer.toBinaryString(arr) + "; digit=" + digit);
            return true; // duplicate found
        }
        n /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println("No dup found, " + Integer.toBinaryString(arr));
    return false;
}
```

Tests:

```java
for (int x : new int[] {1, 10, 11, 1234, 1020, 12344, 1012345}) {
    System.out.printf("checkNum(%d) = %s%n----%n", x, checkNum(x));
}
```

Output:

```
checkNum(1) = false
----
No dup found, 11
checkNum(10) = false
----
Dup found: 0; digit=1
checkNum(11) = true
----
No dup found, 11110
checkNum(1234) = false
----
Dup found: 100; digit=0
checkNum(1020) = true
----
Dup found: 0; digit=4
checkNum(12344) = true
----
Dup found: 111101; digit=1
checkNum(1012345) = true
----
```

Answer (score 0):

Standardly you'd use a `Set` or an array to record which digits you've seen previously. However, if these are not available you can build upon the approach you're already taking - checking if the two low digits (10s and 1s) are the same. However, you'll need to bring each digit next to every other digit for this to work.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static boolean check_num(int n) 
{       
    for(int i = n; i > 10; i /= 10) 
        for(int j = i; j > 10; j = 10 * (j / 100) + (j % 10))
            if(j % 10 == (j / 10) % 10) return true;                
    return false;
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(check_num(543521));
System.out.println(check_num(654321));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```